# move img with mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css-transforms

I want to be able to move an img around within its container once the image is zoomed in, because as you can see once you click the image it becomes too big and you can't see the whole image. Also how can I make the image goes back to normal once it's not being hovered? thanks in advance.

```js
// Zoom in/out clothing img
  $('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('normal-zoom zoom-in');
  });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.normal-zoom {
  transform: scale(1);
  cursor: zoom-in;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.zoom-in {
  transform: scale(1.6);
  cursor: zoom-out;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d53d4e4b03b1013fd40de/1443714010032/lauren-winter-wide-pant-natural_0178.jpg?format=750w" class="image normal-zoom">
  </div>
  <p class="text">Kept in sent gave feel will oh it we. Has pleasure procured men laughing shutters nay. Old insipidity motionless continuing law shy partiality. Depending acuteness dependent eat use dejection. Unpleasing astonished discovered not nor shy. Morning hearted now met yet beloved evening. Has and upon his last here must. Cottage out enabled was entered greatly prevent message. No procured unlocked an likewise. Dear but what she been over gay felt body. Six principles advantages and use entreaties decisively. Eat met has dwelling unpacked see whatever followed. Court in of leave again as am. Greater sixteen to forming colonel no on be. So an advice hardly barton. He be turned sudden engage manner spirit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using `transform: scale()` for the zoom effect it's faster and more correct to modify `transform-origin` to change the center point of the zoom effect on mousemove:

```js
// Zoom in/out clothing img
$('.image').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('normal-zoom zoom-in');
});

$('.image').on('mousemove', function(event) {
  // This gives you the position of the image on the page
  var bbox = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Then we measure how far into the image the mouse is in both x and y directions
  var mouseX = event.clientX - bbox.left;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - bbox.top;

  // Then work out how far through the image as a percentage the mouse is
  var xPercent = (mouseX / bbox.width) * 100;
  var yPercent = (mouseY / bbox.height) * 100;

  // Then we change the `transform-origin` css property on the image to center the zoom effect on the mouse position
  //event.target.style.transformOrigin = xPercent + '% ' + yPercent + '%';
  // It's a bit clearer in jQuery:
  $(this).css('transform-origin', (xPercent+'% ' + yPercent+ '%') );
  // We add the '%' units to make sure the string looks exactly like the css declaration it becomes.

});

// If you want it to automatically trigger on hover
$('.image').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass('zoom-in');
  $(this).removeClass('normal-zoom');
});

// and stop when not hovering
$('.image').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).addClass('normal-zoom');
  $(this).removeClass('zoom-in');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.normal-zoom {
  transform: scale(1);
  cursor: zoom-in;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}

.zoom-in {
  transform: scale(1.6);
  cursor: zoom-out;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d53d4e4b03b1013fd40de/1443714010032/lauren-winter-wide-pant-natural_0178.jpg?format=750w" class="image normal-zoom">
  </div>
  <p class="text">Kept in sent gave feel will oh it we. Has pleasure procured men laughing shutters nay. Old insipidity motionless continuing law shy partiality. Depending acuteness dependent eat use dejection. Unpleasing astonished discovered not nor shy. Morning hearted now met yet beloved evening. Has and upon his last here must. Cottage out enabled was entered greatly prevent message. No procured unlocked an likewise. Dear but what she been over gay felt body. Six principles advantages and use entreaties decisively. Eat met has dwelling unpacked see whatever followed. Court in of leave again as am. Greater sixteen to forming colonel no on be. So an advice hardly barton. He be turned sudden engage manner spirit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW how can I make this effect faster, because it is a bit slow moving the image around, also I'm wondering how to return the image to its original state once it's no longer being hovered.

Comment: Use .mouseout() to set the transformOrigin back to default value.

Comment: I've edited to to make the effect faster (by changing the css transition length) and to add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` listeners to reset when you mouse away

Comment: Hey @Fred Stark, it seems there's an error with your code, the demo isn't working.

Comment: @Fred Stark nvm, I tried it on my code and it works perfectly fine, but the effect is still slow for my taste, nevertheless thank you so much for your help, the `mouseleave` effec is exactly I what wanted!

Comment: Feel free to tweak the CSS transition timing. It should probably be zero for transform-origin

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't notice that you changed the css transition, now it's working perfectly fine, thank you so much dude!. Btw, do you mind explaining to me the functionality of this code, especially this line here `event.target.style.transformOrigin = x * 100 + '% ' + y * 100 + '%';`, sorry about this, Im new at programming and I would like to understand the code for future references. Also, what's the "transform" value is doing to the transition property ?

Comment: I've edited again to include commentary. I changed that specific line with a jQuery version that's a bit clearer. To explain anyway, `event.target` is the HTMLElement moused over (same as `this`), `.style` is the VanillaJS way of setting inline css styles, `transformOrigin` is the equivalent of `transform-origin` in css, and `x * 100 + '% ' + y * 100 + '%'` is constructing the css string (ie `"20% 40%"`), which is 20% in from the left edge and 40% down from the top edge

Comment: Oh and I removed the css transition on everything except the transform, it works much better not

Comment: Woa thank you very much dude, this is really helpful and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mousemove event listener on the image with class `.zoom-in` to change the left and top CSS params. Make sure to set `position:relative;` on the image.

Example:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '.zoom-in', function( event ) {
  $(".text").text(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
  var positionLeft = event.pageX - $(this).width()/2;
  var positionTop = event.pageY - $(this).height()/2;
        $(this).css({'left': positionLeft, 'top': positionTop});
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/3wLhatm5/15/).